# Extra Apostrophe in SQL Statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, special-characters

So I have this chunk of sql text

```
  CASE WHEN LOWER([F16]) = 'matt@me.com' THEN 'Matt'
       WHEN LOWER([F16]) = '''matt@me.com' THEN 'Matt'
```

What are we checking for this value twice? Is it because my SSIS package dumps values from an excel book to a tbl and we're trying to get past random characters that excel has at times?

My question is "Why is the 2nd 'WHEN' have extra apostrophes in it?"

Comment: How are we supposed to know why your SQL is checking something twice? Did you look at your data to see why it's necessary?

Comment: @KenWhite I would think my question was clear, but i have edited so it is more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is imported from Excel, the check may be there to allow for leading ticks that are not visible when you view the workbook.

Excel interprets a single quote as a marker of a text field. When you enter text that would otherwise be interpreted as some other type, adding a single quote prevents Excel from inferring the type.

However, this quote remains part of the data in the cell. Interpreting the data that may include leading quotes requires adding explicit handling for it.

Comment: Thank you, thats what I was thinking but nice to have it confirmed